# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, html

I got this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of undefined`

and it's on the var d section.

```
function sign() {
    var d = document.first.d.value;
    var mon = document.first.mon.value;
    var y = document.first.y.value;
    var curd = new Date(y,mon-1,d);
    var res2 = curd.getMonth();
    var i = 0;
}
```

I don't know what's the problem.
Can anyone help me out.
I can detail it more if you need some.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That's an oldschool `DOM 0` accessing code where elements were referenced by `name=""` eg `name="first"` which is deprecated. Use `document.getElementById` instead of `document.first.d`.

```
<input id="d" value="10" />
<input id="mon" value="02" />
<script>
(function() {
var first = document.getElementById('d');
alert(first.value);
})();
</script>
```

Your code fails because it doesn't get a reference to `document.first` because theres probably no `name=first` but maybe an `id=first`. Make those 3 statements use `gEBI` and set `id`s if you need to, and you should be set.

Comment: i always use this document.getElementById(); but don't know that the old one is deprecated . thanks for info. +1